# Updating ng-repeat array

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've read many questions like this but for some reason haven't found why my code isn't working.

The goal is to have the page load with a list of items loaded by `ng-repeat`, which works fine, but then when the user performs a function, have that `ng-repeat` array replaced with another one of the same structure. It's got through http.

The code is like this.

```
// in HomeController

$scope.content = {
    items: [ {
        title: "hi!"
    } ]
}

$scope.search = function() {
    if ( $scope.query == '' )
        return $scope.content = null

    $http
        .get( '/api/search', { params: 
            { terms: $scope.query }
        } )
        .success( function ( results ) {
            console.log( results)
            $scope.content.items = results
        })
        .error( function ( error ) {
            $flash.error = error
        })
}
```

then

```
// in the HTML

<div ng-controller="HomeController" class="list-container">

    <div class="panel panel-item" ng-repeat="item in content.items">
        <h2 ng-bind="item.title"></h2> // ... etc
```

Then elsewhere there is an `ng-change` that triggers `search()`. I know the `http.get` works because I see it in the console. But it doesn't update the main source of ng-repeat or even the scope, from the looks of it.

---

Is it relevant if this controller is nested in another one?

Comment: provide a plunker. If your http returns in correct format it should work fine as it was working earlier without any problem.

Comment: If your `$http` returns a list which contains duplicates, you have to alter `ng-repeat` like: `ng-repeat="item in content.items track by $index"`

Comment: @MadasuK The Plunker seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/SWddJIEyOVA27Ix7387F

Comment: @Noah: Plnkr seems to work, because you haven't executed everything in it that you're doing in your actual code... Check my answer that compares working and invalid code side-by-side.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

The problem you're having is this line:

```
return $scope.content = null;
```

Because at this point you destroy your object `$scope.content` which means it doesn't have any subordinate properties or anything. So when you afterwards try to assign a value to its property, that property doesn't exist on a `null` variable you get a runtime error:

> Cannot set property 'items' of null

So if you changed upper line to

```
return $scope.content.items = null;
```

everything should work. This way your `content` doesn't get destroyed it just reassigns its inner property a new value.

Or you could also keep your initial line but change assignment afterwards to

```
$scope.content = {
    items: result
};
```

So when you get results you recreate the whole `content` object that may have been destroyed before (assigned to `null`).

But I would personally suggest you change upper problem code line to this:

```
$scope.content.items = [];
return null; // change to whatever return value seems appropriate
```

Which will keep your property as Array as it initially was. You'll just empty it. Sometimes it's best if you think of Javascript as a strong type language and don't execute code that would break in a strongly typed language.

[Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/lixunuziqo/4/edit?html,js,output) with **side-by-side comparison** of both working versions to the one that you're using and doesn't work.

Comment: This is true. But it didn't fix my problem. I'll still mark it correct shortly.

Comment: @noah but did you find the problem with your code? Was it something related to your code in the question or not?

Comment: I'm not sure. Could it be caused by the controller being nested in another one? It goes `MainController` -> `HomeController`.

Comment: No controller nesting shouldn't be a problem. I would change the ng-repeat to call a function and debug that function to actually see the running values...

Comment: I've now made it into a service. For some reason, pushing each item into an empty array seems to work instead of saying `items = results`, even though results seemed to be an array. Now I have `$scope.content = new Content()`, with Content being a different but nearly identical service. Then on the `search()` function I say `$scope.content = new Search()`, then run the command in Search to populate it, `$scope.content.load()`. But that doesn't work, the content stays the same.